# Android contacts integrating, how to stop it?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

I have bought my first android phone(sony xperia m)! I'm so happy. But very strange things happen.

I have installed a skype and it's contacts are migrated to contacts of my phone. I do not ask it to do this! There are no phone numbers in my skype contacts. They are useless there.

I create a google play account, then all apps are connected to my mail. I do not ask them. I have separate accounts at youtube, in mail, in google and in other services. And *I do not want to anybody associate me as one person with all of them*.

Now I understand, I do not know how my data is organized, what relations avoid me create my device, what data it throws over from one to another.

How can I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop contacts syncing, go to:

Settings → Accounts (& Sync) → Skype → uncheck the Sync Contacts checkbox

On my Sony Xperia E:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is already unchecked and all checkboxes with autosync.  But skype contacts are there and all apps are loged in.

Comment: @so-olitary It must have been checked before, after the contacts had already been synced. On my phone, I had to manually delete all the synced contacts after unchecking the box. You can click the menu key > filter > uncheck all the other contacts other than Skype and then OK > delete the visible contacts. This will delete all the Skype contacts

Comment: OK. thank you, skype-problem is solved. About google applications, if auto synchronization is switched off. I can log out fearlessly from recommended accounts and log in to my preferred and phone does not mean, that I want to integrate them?

Comment: @so-olitary Sorry, I don't understand you. You're asking that logging out of a Google App and logging in again on a different Android phone means you don't want the contacts to sync? If so, the answer is *yes*, as long as auto-sync is disabled, the contacts will not be synced on the phone. If my answer helped you, please +1 and tick :)

Comment: No, another account on present phone. I do not what to integrate accaunt of youtube and gmail.

Comment: @so-olitary You can fearlessly login to YouTube and Gmail and then turn off syncing via Settings > Accounts > Google > Gmail. This will mean nothing is synced on your new phone that you don't want

Comment: Thank you. Сoncurrently I tried to break off relations in youtube-app. Very long I searched for log out, but at first moment phone propose me to add a new account. After I loged in, there cherished pararmeters appears. It ask me for synch with other data. Fantastic OS and phone! Everything can be tuned.